# Add Image to Tkinter Class

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a Tkinter app to convert the mailing lists we use at my company. All the functionality seems to work fine I just can't get the logo image to work!

I have created an app without using a Class and it is exactly how I'd want it.

**The way I'd want the app to look:**

[image: The way I'd want the app to look]

However, I can only get the converter to work with this version using a Class:

**Current working version:**

[image: Current working version]

The code for the working version is below (the one without any logo), I've excluded all the excel conversion code as it's quite long.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("SPB Mailing List Cleaner")
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        self.filepath = tk.StringVar()

        convertButton = tk.Button(self, text='Convert',
                                  command=self.convert, bg="#00a69d", fg="white", height="2", width="15")
        convertButton.place(x=242, y=200)

        filepathText = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.filepath)
        filepathText.pack()
        filepathText.place(x=237, y=250)

    def convert(self):
        pass  # left out code

    def show_file_browser(self):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        return self.filename

    def first_browser(self):
        file = self.show_file_browser()
        self.filepath.set(file)

form = tk.Tk()
form.geometry("600x300")
form.resizable(0, 0)

app = Window(form)

form.mainloop()
```

This is the code for the image in the first screenshot (the one with the logo) ('*The way I'd want the app to look*').

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import os
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 300)
canvas.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=3)


#logo
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
logo_label = tk.Label(image = logo)
logo_label.image = logo
logo_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

#instructions
instructions = tk.Label(root, text="Select an appropriate '.xlsx' file for cleaning.")
instructions.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)


def open_file():
    browse_text.set("loading...")
    file = askopenfile(initialdir=os.path.normpath("C://"), parent=root, mode='rb', title="Choose a file", filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")])
    if file:
        print(file.name)


#browse button
browse_text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=browse_text, command=lambda:open_file(), bg="#00a69d", fg="white", height="2", width="15")
browse_text.set("Select File")
browse_btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 150)
canvas.grid(columnspan=3)



root.mainloop()
```

The question is how do I get the logo to work with the version that doesn't have a logo, i.e make the image work within a class.

I would really appreciate any feedback/help on this. I had a look at some posts that describe a similar issue but I'm quite new to coding so can't wrap my head around it all.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. It's unclear where or if the code that creates the image is actually running.

Comment: The question is just basically, how do I get the 2nd screenshot to display like the first?

Comment: No, this isn't a MRE. You provided a block of code just floating out in space, with no connection to the rest of the code.

Comment: This question isn't clear. You seem to know how to create an image. What's stopping you from adding the second block of code to the first block?

Comment: I don't know how that would work within a class? Could you answer this for me?

Comment: Nevermind you were right, I fixed this now!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Things you have to do:

- load the image in class.
- Currently Tkinter only supports , [the GIF, PGM, PPM, and PNG file formats as of Tkinter 8.6](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/)

To support other file formats such as PNG,JPG, JPEG, or BMP, you can use an image library such as Pillow to convert them into the supported format.

```
image = Image.open('./assets/python.jpg')
python_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

self.label=Label(image=python_image)
```

The another solution is to use to make the image variable a class variable by adding `self.` so final thing would look like `self.img_var_name=image`.

Alternatively you can append the images in a list, or use

```
image = image)
```

The goals is to increase the refrence count of image variable.

See [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I just had to put the image code inside the init_window function.

```
def init_window(self):

        #logo
        logo = Image.open('logo.png')
        logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
        logo_label = tk.Label(image = logo)
        logo_label.image = logo
        logo_label.place(x=160, y=20)

        #instructions
        instructions = tk.Label(form, text="Select an appropriate '.xlsx' file for cleaning.")
        instructions.place(x=180, y=280)

        self.master.title("SPB Mailing List Cleaner")
        self.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)

        self.filepath = tk.StringVar()


        convertButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Convert',
                               command = self.convert, bg="#00a69d", fg="white", height="2", width="15")
        convertButton.place(x = 242, y = 200)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).